# Problems importing MoPub SDK with Phonegap

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, mopub

I tried to follow the documentation for getting started with MoPub SDK using Eclipse (https://dev.twitter.com/mopub/android/getting-started). It says to import the SDK folder and add it as a reference in Android Library for your project folder. I also added the three .jar's in my project's build path but so far I still see 200+ errors. Does anyone here have experience with why MoPub SDK keeps giving me these kind of errors even though I configured the build path?

[image]

Comment: So can you give more information about the Errors or the information of the console?

Comment: did you follow the steps as mentioned in the link with the title "Eclipse Integration" ?

Comment: It would be better to use Android studio for development rather than sticking to Eclipse since android dev community suggest that. If it would not take much time to migrate to Android studio, these integration will be much simpler..